# StretchRectangle on surface from one device to another

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d

Is it possible to use [StretchRectangle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms897027.aspx) to draw a surface created on one device, to a surface created on another device? It are two devices created for two different controls.

I keep getting an `InvalidCallException`. Both surfaces are render targets, are of the same format and are placed in the default pool.

I suppose the problem lies in the two different devices? How can I copy this surface?

UPDATE:

I am having some succes by using [`LockRectangle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.direct3d.surface.lockrectangle%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and using [`GraphicsStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.graphicsstream_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to read from and write to another surface. I'm saying *some* success since I notice *something* moving is visible, but I still have to determine how many bytes to read/write and such, which rectangle ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not possible. After continued experimentations I was able to copy a valid surface, but there is a lot of extra effort involved besides the following code. This is just the actual copy.

```
byte[] data = new byte[surfaceByteCount];
GraphicsStream sourceStream = sourceSurface.LockRectangle(area, LockFlags.ReadOnly);
sourceStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
sourceSurface.UnlockRectangle();

GraphicsStream targetStream = targetSurface.LockRectangle(area, LockFlags.Discard);
targetStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
targetSurface.UnlockRectangle();

device.Present();
```

Comment: So why not do as above to copy to a temporary target on the other device then stretch rect the temporary?

Comment: @Goz: Right now I tested scaling down on one device, and copying that. Both work I guess, depending on whether you are scaling up or down one might be more suitable to limit the amount of bytes that need to be copied by the CPU.

Comment: Very true.  Though its worth bearing in mind that one device may be hardware accelerated where the other isn't ...